# Teradata Prepare object error

Tags: sas, teradata, mod-auth-passthrough

I am trying to access the SAS table which I made outside of Teradata Passthrough in working space for query run. Now it gives me an error. My question is how to access the table **not in teradata** inside the passthrough

```
proc sql;
    connect to teradata (user="&user_id.@LDAP" password="&TERADATA_PASS" server='ABC' 
connection=global database="GTY");
    select * from connection to teradata(
    select * from mm)
;
quit;
```

**mm** is not in teradata but made in working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't access that in passthrough directly.  You either need to run your query using `libname` access to the Teradata, or you need to put the information you need into a macro variable or text file that could be included in the passthrough query.  In passthrough you can only access what you could access in an interactive Teradata session - so unless you have SAS defined as an ODBC or such provider for Teradata, it's a no go.

Typically what I do in this case is first try to execute the entire process through `libname` access, and if that fails (either because of execution time or because of a need for passthrough-only elements like stored procedures) then I use `libname` access to load the table to a table inside the RDBMS (Teradata here).  Then it's available in your passthrough session for use (as a native Teradata table).

Comment: I thought the same. Libname just takes an eternity to solve and hence I thought I will go through the Pass Through. However it seems to me rather inconsistent. Since "macro variables" made in working direcory are usable inside the passthrough but "table" are not.

Comment: Macro variables are just text pop-ins, so when the passthrough is translated to teradata, it resolves the values of macro variables.  Datasets are their own thing; the libname access method is intended to allow you to access them.  Simply copying a table via libname access should be no slower than any other method; the only reason libname is slower is when it requires you to download the entire table from teradata prior to doing something (which in the case of uploading a table is of course not relevant).